# JavaScript error: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to check if a `data.objectId` already exists in the array `msgArr`. For that I am running the code below:

```
var exists = msgArr.objectId.includes(data.objectId);

if(exists === false){
   msgArr.push({"objectId":data.objectId,"latLont":data.latLont,"isOnline":data.isOnline});
}
```

The array looks like the following:

```
var msgArr = [
  {isOnline:true,latLont:"123",objectId:"on0V04v0Y9"},
  {isOnline:true,latLont:"1",objectId:"FpWBmpo0RY"},
  {isOnline:true,latLont:"48343",objectId:"Qt6CRXQuqE"} 
 ]
```

I am getting the error below:

> Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Comment: `msgArr` is an array. It doesn't have an `objectId`.

Comment: @DaveNewton it has..

Comment: @Folky.H: Then you have no problems.

Comment: @squint then, why I receive: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Comment: Because `msgArr` is an array. It doesn't have an `objectId`.

Comment: If you're wondering how to search an array to see if contains an object with a particular ID, Google that and you'll find plenty of solutions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As the comments say: the javascript array object has no property `objectId`.
Looking at the objects in this array it's clear that they have it, so to check if a certain element exists you can do so using [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
var exists = msgArr.some(o => o.objectId === data.objectId);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's telling you that you're trying to access a property on an undefined object. The `msgArr` object doesn't have a property `objectID` at all, which means it's **undefined**. Since that doesn't exist, there's no way for it to have an `includes` property available of any type.

What you need is to access an object in the array, not the array itself.  Something like `msgArr[0].objectID` would refer to an instantiated object. You could even use the array functions to check if something exists based on its objectID with a filter function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Dave Newton is right. An array doesn't have an objectId!

Maybe your "array" isn't a real array. Maybe it's an object which contains an array... I don't know... but in that case, you would have to code something like this:

```
var exist = msArr["objectId"] !== undefined
```

than "exist" which is a boolean contains the info if "msArr" has an property/field called "objectId"

Comment: oops, my wrong :) the array contains an object which has that value... there is a good answer btw...